# Convergence of a sequence of uniformly integrable functions.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ be a probability space, $(\mathscr{F}_n)$ a filtration on $\mathscr{A}$, and $\nu$ be a finite measure dominated by $P$. Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of real random variables  with values in $[0,1]$, adapted to $\mathscr{F}$, i.e. for each $n$, $X_n$ is $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable. Suppose that
$$
\int_A X_n \mathrm{d}P = \nu(A) \quad\text{
for each $A \in \mathscr{F}_n$.}
$$
How can I prove that $(X_n)$ converges almost surely (i.e. almost everywhere), or in $L^1$, to an integrable random variable $Z$?

---

**My attempt.**

I have tried to prove that $(X_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(P)$. To this end, I  did
$$
\begin{split}
\int |X_n - X_m|\mathrm{d}P &= \int_{\{X_n \ge X_m\}} (X_n - X_m)\mathrm{d}P + \int_{\{X_n < X_m\}} (X_m - X_n)\mathrm{d}P \cr
&=\int_{\{X_n \ge X_m\}} X_n \mathrm{d}P - \int_{\{X_n \ge X_m\}} X_m \mathrm{d}P 
 +\int_{\{X_n < X_m\}} X_m \mathrm{d}P - \int_{\{X_n < X_m\}} X_n \mathrm{d}P 
\end{split}
$$
Now, I could prove this if the following statement was true:

> For every $A \in \mathscr{F}_m$ there exist $B_n,C_n \in \mathscr{F}_n$ such that
> $$ B_n \subseteq A \subseteq C_n \qquad\text{and}\qquad P(C_n\setminus B_n) \to 0$$

Using this result, in fact, I would find that
$$
\begin{split}
\int |X_n - X_m|\mathrm{d}P & \le 
  \int_{C_n} X_n\mathrm{d}P - \int_{B_n} X_m\mathrm{d}P
  + \int_{B_n^c} X_m\mathrm{d}P - \int_{C_n^c} X_n\mathrm{d}P \cr
&= \nu(C_n) - \nu(B_n) + \nu(B_n^c) - \nu(C_n^c) \cr
&= \nu(C_n) - \nu(B_n) + 1- \nu(B_n) - 1 + \nu(C_n) \cr
&= 2[\nu(C_n) - \nu(B_n)] \cr
&= 2\nu(C_n\setminus B_n).
\end{split}
$$

**Note.** I have little hope that the previous argument may be fixed. However, I might add the property that each $\mathscr{F}_n$ is generated by a finite partition $\mathscr{P}_n$ of $\Omega$ and that the partition $\mathscr{P}_m$ is finer than $\mathscr{P}_n$ if $m \ge n$.

Comment: Do you know any sufficient conditions for the pointwise convergence of martingales?

Comment: I actually stated the problem in a probabilistic language, but it is actually a problem of purely measure theory. The condition on the measure $Q$ is stronger than martingales. There is a convergence theorem that says that if it is a martingale bounded in $L^1(P)$ it converges in $L^1$ towards an integrable random variable $Z$ which closes the martingale. But I hoped I could avoid such a strong result in this case.

Comment: Do you really want $Q$ to be a probability measure? Since $0\leq X_n\leq 1$ and $\int_{\Omega}X_n\,\mathrm{d}P=Q(\Omega)=1$ implies that $X_1=1$ $P$-a.s.

Comment: Actually $Q$ can be only a finite measure. Not important it to be normalised. Though still $Q \le P$.

Comment: That makes much more sense now. Perhaps you might want to consider updating your question accordingly for other users.

Comment: Your (new) statement is not clear. You choose for $m>n$ and a fixed $A \in \mathcal{F}_m$ some $C_n,B_n \in \mathcal{F}_n$ and in the end you want to have $$P(C_n\setminus B_n) \to 0$$ But $\to 0$ for what? For $n\to\infty$? But then you will have $n>m$ for $n$ large enough and you can always choose $C_n = B_n = A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\int_A X_n \mathrm{d}P = E[X_n1_A] = \nu(A) \quad\text{
for each $A \in \mathscr{F}_n$.}$$
But if we have a closer look this almost looks like the property a conditional expectation has to fulfill if we assume $$X_n = E[Y|\mathcal{F}_n]$$ for a random variable $Y$ for which it holds $$E[Y1_A] = \nu(A)$$

Can we find such a r.v. $Y$? Indeed! Because $\nu$ is dominated by $P$ it's absolutely continuous in $P$, so $$\nu \ll P$$ holds and the random variable $$Y := \frac{d\nu}{dP}$$ is well defined.

And now for $Y$ it holds by construction and the theorem of randon nikodym $$E[Y1_A] = \int_A Y \mathrm{d}P = \int_A 1 \,d\nu = \nu(A)\quad\text{
for each $A \in \mathscr{F}_n$.}$$

So with the property for $X_n$ we easily check that $X_n$ is indeed a conditional expectation of $Y$ w.r.t to $\mathcal{F}_n$.

So we have $$X_n = E[Y|\mathcal{F}_n]\quad \text{ for all } n$$ and we can deal with tools for martingal convergence.

Comment: This proof is very nice and clear. However, I hoped not to use Radon-Nikodym theorem, because it would be a “lemma” to prove Radon-Nikodym theorem. Actually, I also know the result is an easy consequence of Doob’s convergence theorem for martingales, but I hoped not to use it as well.